# cleveref v0.21.3 causing some \cref's not to print correctly

Tags: cleveref

I recently updated to the current version of cleveref (2018/03/03 v0.21.3), and now some `\cref`'s are not printing correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{section}{section}{sections}
\Crefname{section}{Section}{Sections}

\crefname{subsection}{subsection}{subsections}
\Crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}\label{sec1}

\subsection{First subsection}\label{sec1.1}

\subsubsection{First subsubsection}\label{sec1.1.1}

We refer to \cref{sec1}, \cref{sec1.1}, and \cref{sec1.1.1}.

\Cref{sec1} is referred to.

\Cref{sec1.1} is referred to.

\Cref{sec1.1.1} is referred to.

\end{document}
```

`\cref{sec1.1.1}` should be printing as "subsection 1.1.1", but instead it's printing as "section 1.1.1"; and `\Cref{sec1.1.1}` has a similar problem. This was not a problem with cleveref v0.19; I downloaded the v0.19 from http://www.dr-qubit.org/cleveref.html, and it still worked fine.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: This looks like a bug. You could cure it with an explicity `\Crefname{subsubsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}

Comment: Have you informed the author about this?

Comment: I have emailed the author about this. I haven't gotten a response yet. Also, with a custom document class file that I use that defines a custom format for `\cref`'s to equations, the custom format sometimes isn't used. Again, this was not a problem with v0.19.

Answer (score 2):

Some tests:

### TeX Live 2018/pretest, `cleveref` version 0.21.3

> We refer to section 1, subsection 1.1, and section 1.1.1.

### TeX Live 2017, `cleveref` version 0.21.1

> We refer to section 1, subsection 1.1, and section 1.1.1.

### TeX Live 2016, `cleveref` version 0.19

> We refer to section 1, subsection 1.1, and subsection 1.1.1.

### TeX Live 2012, `cleveref` version 0.18.9

> We refer to section 1, subsection 1.1, and subsection 1.1.1.

There was no change in `cleveref` from TeX Live 2013 up to 2017.

If you remove the `\crefname` and `\Crefname` instructions, you get

> We refer to section 1, section 1.1, and section 1.1.1.

with all versions.

However, the documentation says

> For convenience, if they have not been otherwise customised by the end of the preamble, the cross-reference name (and label format) for `subsection` is by default inherited from that of `section`, and that of `subsubsection` is inherited from `subsection` (which might itself have been inherited from `section`). Similarly for `subappendix`, `subsubappendix` and `subsubsubappendix`, and also for `enumii`, `enumiii`, `enumiv` and `enumv`, which inherit from `enumi`. Finally, `subfigure` and `subtable` inherit from `figure` and `table`, respectively.

So it seems like a bug either in version 0.21 or in the documentation.

Anyway, I don't think one should use “subsection 1.1”, as the double number by itself specifies the sectioning level. Have mercy of your readers and spare them with the horrible “subsection”.